# help me restore a database

Tags: mysql, backup, syntax

I have a database backup that I'm trying to load so that I can extract some historical averages. I think it was a MySQL database, but with some syntax adjustments I was able to create the one and only table I need in Oracle 11g. However, I'm having problems with the INSERT INTO portion of the backup. Basically, some of these text fields were taken directly from fields on our website, and whenever users entered an apostrophe, it messes up everything that follows. Finding all instances of this would take a very long time...

Is there any way to handle this?

Also, all the text in SQL Developer runs horizontally on 2 or 3 rows. Is there any way to fix that? It makes for a lot of side-scrolling instead of vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpMyAdmin to reload the database into mySQL.